# Sequelize Migrate Not Recognising Dotenv

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, dotenv

I am able to run migrate command when I specify the database name, user and password directly. But when I provide with env variable/value. It says no database selected. I have installed `npm i dotenv`

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

dotenv is required.

```
require('dotenv').config();
    module.exports = {
      development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        logging: false
      },
      test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        logging: false
      },
      production: {
        use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL'
      }
    };
```

I have the following in .env file thus:

```
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS= 
DB_NAME=road_rescue_dev
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

This works

```
development: {
        username: "root",
        password: "",
        database: road_rescue_dev,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        logging: false
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to add this at the top ?

`require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: No, it is there.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/kylewhittemore/full-stack-sequelize/blob/ae923742a1941843585669843060737d29212710/config/config.js

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue before.
I figured out I have to

1. require('dotenv').config() in the config file (just like you did)
2. set .sequelizerc in the root directory  like below
3. set .sequelie file to point config, migrations, models, seeds directory from root directory
4. and you should run `npx seuqlie-cli db:migrate` form root directory.

for some reason, if I run `npx seuqlie-cli db:migrate` from sequleize directory, it does not read dotenv variables.

I'm still figuring out why, but it works

this is my directory looks like
[image]

my .sequlizerc file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports={
    config: path.resolve('src/sequelize/config','config.js'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/migrations'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/seeders'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/models')
}
```

Also posted  question about this
[Sequelize migration doesnot read dotenv variable if I don't run it from root directory. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826152/sequelize-migration-doesnot-read-dotenv-variable-if-i-dont-run-it-from-root-di)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `NODE_ENV` variable exist either in `package.json` or `.env` file. Sequelize migration picks environment from `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to specify the path of .env in the dotenv's config. Like:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: 'your/path/to/.env'});
```