# Sequelize migration doesnot read dotenv variable if I don't run it from root directory. why?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, dotenv

This is what I did

1. require('dotenv').config() in the config file
2. set .sequelizerc in the root directory  like below
3. set .sequelie file to point config, migrations, models, seeds directory from root directory
4. ran `npx seuqlie-cli db:migrate` form root directory. It work!
5. ran `npx seuqlie-cli db:migrate` form sequelize directory. It doesn't read dotenv variable and come with `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

and I want to know what is differences between 4 and 5..?

this is my directory looks like
[image]

my .sequlizerc file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports={
    config: path.resolve('src/sequelize/config','config.js'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/migrations'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/seeders'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('src/sequelize/models')
}
```

and my config file

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
    charset: "utf8",
    collate: "utf8_general_ci",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    define: {
      underscored: true
    }
  },
...
}
```

Comment: That’s just how `dotenv` works it assume the .env file would be at the same level where you run the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use the path property for the dotenv so it is not restricted to the folder that has been called.

```
dotenv.config({ path: `${process.cwd()}/.env`})
```